# How do I create a formula in excel for this fee structure?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a cell that has a value `A1 = 3,500,000`.

I want to calculate a fee on that $3.5M that follows this formula:

> 7% on the first million, plus.
> 5% on the second million, plus.
> 3% on the third million, plus.
> 2% after that.

Ideally I would like all of this to happen in 1 cell, so 1 formula in 1 cell rather than having a whole table or a sheet that does this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to solve this with a single formula in a single cell, but if you want to make your formulas easy to follow and easy to change, a table would be cleaner.

--

**Single Cell Solution**

For a single cell solution, if the value is in A1, this formula will calculate your tiered fees:

= A1 * 0.07 + MAX(A1-1000000,0) * -0.02 + MAX(A1-2000000,0) * -0.02 + MAX(A1-3000000,0) * -0.01

You multiply the total value by .07, and then for each tier subtract off the difference in fee between the new tier and the previous tier (there are numerous ways to do this--I've just provided 1 example).

--

**Simple Table Solution**

For a simple table solution, you could do the following:

[image]

*The formulas to calculate the value in each tier*:

E2: =MIN(C2,$A$1)

E3: =MIN(C3,$A$1)-SUM($E$2:E2)

E4: =MIN(C4,$A$1)-SUM($E$2:E3)

E5: =MAX($A$1-C4 ,0)

*The formula to calculate the total fee*:

D6: =SUMPRODUCT(D2:D5,E2:E5)

This setup is dynamic; you can change the thresholds or the fees and the formulas will still work.

---

<sup>If you may need additional tiers in the future, an XML table is recommended. If you will only ever use 4 tiers, but the thresholds and fees for those tiers may change, the simple table above will suffice</sup>

Comment: Good point re: having a simple table. I like what you have proposed. I am going to try it to confirm the formulas work. But thanks for the answer. Once I confirm it works for me, I will accept. If I have any questions, I will come back here.

Answer (score 2):

***I would like to show 3 possibilities.***

[image]

1. *Separately Calculate value of Tier 1 then 2, tier 3 and next would for
   tier 4, and finally get the Total.*

**For this check the formula in cells:**

**E2:**   `=IF(D2<=1000000, D2*0.07, 1000000*0.07)`

**F2:**    `=IF(D2>1000000, IF(D2<=2000000, (D21-1000000)*0.05, 1000000*0.05), 0)`

**G2:**
`=IF(D2>2000000, IF(D2<=3000000, (D2-2000000)*0.03, 1000000*0.03), 0)`

**H2:** `=IF(D2>3000000, (D2-3000000)*0.02, 0)`

*And the Final one is in **I2:*** `=SUM(E2:H2)`

---

*2. Another is Single formula solution in `I5`.*

**Cell I5:**

```
=IF(D2<=1000000, D2*0.07, IF(D2<=2000000, 1000000*0.07 + (D2-1000000)*0.05, IF(D2<=3000000, 1000000*0.07 + 1000000*0.05 + (D2-2000000)*0.03, 1000000*0.07 + 1000000*0.05 + 1000000*0.03 + (D2-3000000)*0.02)))
```

---

*3. And the last one is Formula is in `I7` for Higher Version of Excel where the LET functions has been used.*

**Cell I7:**

```
=LET( amount, D2,
        tier1, MIN(amount, 1000000),
        tier2, MAX(0, MIN(amount, 2000000) - 1000000),
        tier3, MAX(0, MIN(amount, 3000000) - 2000000),
        tier4, MAX(0, amount - 3000000),
        tier1*0.07 + tier2*0.05 + tier3*0.03 + tier4*0.02)
```

**N.B.** *Adjust the cell references as needed.*

Comment: Thanks for this. I like that you gave me multiple options. Ultimately I prefer the overall solution that Wizard gave. It fits my specific scenario better, but yours gave me lots to think about. I appreciate the effort. Upvoted!

Comment: @marcamillion ,,, thanks and happy to learn that you found my suggest methods quite a useful ,,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 2):

One can use a properly structured lookup table for this (as well as for the very similar tax computation problems.

Of your commission table

- Column 1 = the base amount of the sales
- Column 2 = the percent on each tier
- Column 3 = the amount of commission earned prior to that tier

In the table below:
`G1: 0`
`G2: =(E3-E2)*F2+G2`
and fill down as far as needed

Then with data in `A1`

```
=(A1-VLOOKUP(A1,commissionTbl,1))*VLOOKUP(A1,commissionTbl,2)+VLOOKUP(A1,commissionTbl,3)
```

[image]

Note that if your commission structure changes, it is simple to edit the table -- much simpler than editing formulas.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. On the surface, it feels A BIT unintuitive, because the fee/commission gradually grows from 0, which is the opposite of the actual way the fee structure works in this specific case. I went with another answer, but I upvoted yours because it gave me something to think about!

Comment: @marcamillion I don't understand what you wrote. I would think your commission **increases** the more you sell. It is only the **percentage** on each tier that **decreases**. Which is exactly what this does (see the percent column). Note that the result is the same for all of the methods shown in the various answers.